# Как сделать изображение блоком?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как сделать данную картинку блоком и поместить внутри нее текст?
Затем, чтобы изображение меняло размер в зависимости от разрешения монитора?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```css
.frame {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDuvb.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 3vw;
}

.frame:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-top: 171.5%; /* соотношение ширины/высоты картинки рамки */
}

.frame-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 58% 20% 28%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="frame-content">
    <h2>Зимнее утро</h2>
    <p>
      Мороз и солнце; день чудесный!<br> Еще ты дремлешь, друг прелестный –<br> Пора, красавица, проснись;<br> Открой сомкнуты негой взоры<br> Навстречу северной Авроры,<br> Звездою севера явись!<br> Вечор, ты помнишь, вьюга злилась,<br> На мутном небе
      мгла носилась;
    </p>
    <p>
      Луна, как бледное пятно,<br> Сквозь тучи мрачные желтела,<br> И ты печальная сидела –<br> А нынче... погляди в окно:
    </p>
    <p>
      Под голубыми небесами<br> Великолепными коврами,<br> Блестя на солнце, снег лежит;<br> Прозрачный лес один чернеет,
    </p>
    <p>
      ...
    </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Как раз учу сейчас с дочкой. Будем с Вашего ответа учить.